# variable conditional compilation tag to update target framework

Tags: c#, visual-studio, variables, tags, conditional-compilation

Is there a way to create a tag variable

Example. #if target_framework
where target_framework = NET_471;

So that if i want to change the target framework i can just change

target_framework = NET_461;

Comment: You can do `#IF NET_471` where you define `NET_471` in the "Conditional Compilation Symbols" (Properties>Build>General) only for .NET 4.7.1...

Comment: By doing this, i will still need to update the code to eg NET481 if a new version come out. I was hoping for a way to define a "Conditional Compilation variable" so that i do not have to edit in the code it self. Example: #define targetframework1 = NET471 so that i just have to change this definition: eg #define targetframework1 = NET481

Comment: No, you can ["#define"](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/preprocessor-directives/preprocessor-define) a compilation symbol but it isn't like C++, they exist or they don't, they cannot have a value. If you use `#define` instead of the compilation symbol you just have to remember that the `#define`'s scope is file-only, whereas `/define` or the compilation symbol in the properties is project wide.

Comment: However i do not want to use #define. I want something that does not interfere with the code maybe a configuration in the .csproj like using define constant or smth but i do not know how to do it.

Comment: The closest thing I think you may be able to get is the [`ConditionalAttribute`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.diagnostics.conditionalattribute(v=vs.110).aspx), but it can only be applied to methods, but will compile based on defined compilation symbols, but you still have to define them.

Comment: Wondering what your real intention is? If you can change your target framework anytime you do not use new language features. So why do you want to target 4.71 if it seems like 4.61 is ok? Is something described [here](https://weblog.west-wind.com/posts/2017/Jan/09/Faking-out-the-NET-Runtime-Version) your intetion?

Comment: I dont know why you would want to do this but maybe this could be done by including something like `<DefineConstants>$(TargetFrameworks) </DefineConstants>` in your csproj file. This should get you defines like `net461`, `net471`, etc.

Comment: @ArgusMagnus not really. i am not entirely sure the reason why. I guess the team wants to keep it up to date. Anyways thanks for the help, I was able to use <DefineConstants>$(TargetFrameworks) </DefineConstants> in my .cspoj.

Comment: Do you happen to know what to add into the .props file of the solution so that every project will have this <DefineConstants>$(TargetFrameworks) </DefineConstants>

Comment: I added an answer, note that I've come to believe that it should be `$(TargetFramework)`, without the `s`. Although it should not matter as long as you have only one target framework.

Answer (score 0):

I dont know why you would want to do this but maybe this could be done by including something like `<DefineConstants>$(TargetFramework)</DefineConstants>` in your csproj file. This should get you defines like net461, net471, etc

In a prop file you would iclude this in a `PropertyGroup` element.